# How to turn off VPU recover in OpenCL

Tags: c++, macos, opencl

I'm running some code on the GPU with OpenCL, and the code times out. I've done some research and think that the problem is that VPU recover thinks that the program has crashed. How can I disable VPU recover?

I have not found any way to turn off VPU recover on MacOS (I'm using a mac to run the program). The code in the kernel file that is giving me trouble is below:

```
int powmod(int base, int exponent, int modulus) {
    int r = 1;
    while (exponent > 0) {
        if (exponent & 1) {
            r = (r*base)%modulus;
        }
        exponent = exponent >> 1;
        base = (base*base)%modulus;
    }
    return r;
}
```

This function will always receive a base of 16, and the exponent will be in the range of 10,000 to 100,000. With small numbers in the range of 10 to 100, the code runs properly, but with bigger numbers, the code doesn't run.

How can I stop the program from timing out?